# How to check if item exists in pivot table then show a message in the view depending on result?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I want to be able to check if the current user that is signed in has any jobs in their `watchlist` table. If they have I want to display a button that says "Currently watching" else have a button that says "Add to watchlist" in my `view` called `viewListings` which displays all of the listings listed in the `job_listings` table.

I have the logic working in the `ListingController`. But I need to know how I can apply this logic in my view: `viewListings`. How do I do this?

**I have the following database setup:**

[image]

**ListingController:**

```
<?php namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\JobListing;
use App\User;
use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Http\Requests\CreateListingRequest;
use App\Watchlist;

// use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Request;
use Session;
use Auth;
use Carbon\Carbon;
use Input;
use Redirect;
use URL;
use File;
use Hugeform;

// use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File;

class ListingController extends Controller {


    public function __construct()
    {
        // This will send the user to the login page if they are not
        // logged in except for the index page
        $this->middleware('auth', ['except' => ['index', 'show']]);
    }

    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    public function index()
    {

        $listings = JobListing::all();
        $joblisting_ids = JobListing::lists('job_id');


        // This is the logic that is working, but need to get this to the view?
        foreach ($joblisting_ids as $id) {

            if (Watchlist::where('user_id', '=', Auth::user()->id)->where('job_id', '=', $id)->get()->first()) {
                echo 'Currently watching this'.'<p>';

            } else {
                echo 'Add to watchlist'.'<p>';
            }
        }
        // Need to pass something to the view here so I can print out if the job is in the watchlist table or not

        // return view('listings.viewListings', compact('listings'));
    }
```

**viewListings.blade.php**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1 inner-content">
            @if(Session::has('flash_message'))
                <div class="alert alert-success listing-success" role="alert">{!! Session::get('flash_message') !!}</div> 
            @endif
            <h2>Listings page</h2>
            {!! HTML::link('/listings/create', 'Create a Job Listing', ['class' => 'btn btn-success']) !!}
            {!! HTML::link('/listings/myjobs', 'My Jobs', ['class' => 'btn btn-info']) !!}
            {!! HTML::link('watchlist', 'My Watchlist', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary']) !!}
            <hr>
            @if (Auth::check())
                <h4> Welcome {{ Auth::user()->username }} </h4>
                <h3> Welcome ID: {{ Auth::user()->id }} </h3>
                <h3> Another Version ID: {{ Auth::id() }} </h3>
            @endif
        @foreach ($listings as $listing)
                <div class="job-full-wrap">
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        <div class="job-left-wrapper">
                            <a href="../listings/{{ $listing->job_id }}"><h3>{{ $listing->position_title }} </h3></a>
                            <h5>{{ $listing->company_name }}  | {{ $listing->city }}  | {{ $listing->job_type }} </h5>

                            <!-- Need to add logic in here to show either a link or button that will say 'Add to watchlist' or 'currently watching' -->
                            <!-- <a class="add-watchlist" href="watchlist/add/{{ $listing->job_id }}" id="{{ $listing->job_id }}">Add to watchlist</a> -->

                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-2">
                        <div class="job-right-wrapper">
                            <img class="img-responsive" src="{{ '../uploaded_images/'.$listing->logo_path }}" alt="">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="clearfix"></div>
                </div>
            @endforeach
        </div>
    </div> <!-- End of row -->

</div>
```

**Watchlist model:**

```
<?php namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;


class Watchlist extends Model {

    protected $primaryKey = 'job_id';

    protected $table = 'watchlist';

    protected $fillable = ['user_id', 'job_id'];

}
```

**User model:**

```
    <?php namespace App;

    use Illuminate\Auth\Authenticatable;
    use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
    use Illuminate\Auth\Passwords\CanResetPassword;
    use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable as AuthenticatableContract;
    use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\CanResetPassword as CanResetPasswordContract;

    class User extends Model implements AuthenticatableContract, CanResetPasswordContract {

        use Authenticatable, CanResetPassword;

        /**
         * The database table used by the model.
         *
         * @var string
         */
        protected $table = 'users';

        /**
         * The attributes that are mass assignable.
         *
         * @var array
         */
        protected $fillable = ['username','firstname', 'lastname', 'email', 'password', 'role'];

        /**
         * The attributes excluded from the model's JSON form.
         *
         * @var array
         */
        protected $hidden = ['password', 'remember_token'];

        public function watchlist() {

            return $this->belongsToMany('\App\JobListing', 'watchlist', 'user_id', 'job_id');
        }

    }
```

**JobListing model:**

```
<?php namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class JobListing extends Model {

    protected $primaryKey = 'job_id';

    protected $table = 'job_listings';

    protected $fillable = ['user_id', 'position_title', 'description', 'category', 'job_type',
                            'city','company_name','company_url','logo_path','how_to_apply', 'expiry_date', 'status'];

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your controller function, you can set a dynamic property on each listing item as you discover whether the listing is currently watched or not.

```
public function index()
{

    $listings = JobListing::all();

    foreach ($listings as $listing) {
        if (Watchlist::where('user_id', '=', Auth::user()->id)->where('job_id', '=', $listing->job_id)->get()->first()) {
            $listing->watching = true;
        } else {
            $listing->watching = false;
        }
    }
    // Need to pass something to the view here so I can print out if the job is in the watchlist table or not

    // return View::make('listings.viewListings')->with(['listings' => $listings]);
}
```

Inside your foreach loop in your view, you now have access to the property which you can check like so:

```
@foreach ($listings as $listing)
    @if ($listing->watching)
        //"Currently watching" button
    @else
        //"Add to watchlist" button
    @endif
@endforeach
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I knew it would be something simple like that :)